# How can I pass parameters to a script block in a new process

Tags: powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

I want to start a new powershell session from pwsh core to run some code that is designed to run in powershell 5.1 (it checks the version table).

I can get the script block to execute fine, but I want to pass variable values from my pwsh session to the new session.

An example that isn't working is:

```
7.0.3: >_ $block = {param($name)Write-Host "Hello, $name. How are you?"}
7.0.3: >_ start powershell -argumentlist "-noexit $block 'friend'"
```

new window opens:

```
5.1: >_ Hello,  . How are you? friend
5.1: >_
```

However, when I wrap this in a full blown `.ps1` script it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `$block` variable is not defined in the new scope. This works.

```
start powershell -ArgumentList '-noexit & {param($name)Write-Host "Hello, $name. How are you?"} friend'
```

I used the & invoke method, you could also use .

```
start powershell -ArgumentList '-noexit . {param($name)Write-Host "Hello, $name. How are you?"} friend'
```

output in the new console

```
Hello friend . How are you?
```

Comment: I think I may need to clarify. You have the "friend" value hard-coded into the arg list. I need to get the value from a session var in pwsh 7 into a new process of powershell 5.1 that should execute a script block. I'm interfacing with a module that only runs in 5.1 and needs a new session as admin, so I want to collect data from my typical 7 session and open a new 5.1 session and give it those values.